# What is on my cat that's biting me?

Tags: cats, biting, fleas

I live in Texas. I have an indoor cat who is 14 years old. Somehow we got fleas. But I am 99.9% sure of the fleas have been eradicated. I've not seen a flea or caught one in the traps in the house for months.

My cat is regularly treated with advantage from the vet and I thoroughly sprayed and bombed two times and got rid of them.

And yet I'm still noticing that's it on my body from time to time and it's usually after I pet my cat. If I pet the cat, I'll notice by its on my hand or arm, etc.

I don't understand what it could be that is biting me. He's not really digging or scratching very much.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! What do you spot on your skin? Maybe a picture would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. I agree that a picture of the bites could help a lot because by the color and distribution of byte marks you can sometimes tell what caused them. Please [edit] your question to upload one clear and  sharp picture.